# Animate to combined paths

Tags: animation, path

I just started to blender animations and I am trying to animate a sphere to move along combined paths: a straight line followed by a semicircle and then another straight line (as shown below).

In my trial, I added a `path` and struggled to shape it along the desired format, but couldn't fit it.

Any help, please? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: so your question is more about how to model a bezier than how to animate?

Comment: Yes, @moonboots I am more concerned about the bezier! Thank you! I just checked the answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your question is about the path itself, you can create a bezier circle. In *Edit* mode select all and press <kbd>V</kbd> > *Set Handle Type* to switch from *Automatic* to *Aligned*:

[image]

Then select the left part of the circle and press <kbd>X</kbd> > *Delete Segments*:

[image]

Then select the 2 ends, press <kbd>E</kbd> to extrude then type the axis:

[image]

Comment: Doh too slow... or free handle type.  https://pasteall.org/media/5/7/576250be386f1b0c347c2f796bf57276.gif

Comment: good video batFinger...but without keys or voice the viewer (if he/she is a beginner) has no idea what keys you are typing. ;)

Comment: @Chris see answer above for explanation.  Created gif to go with an answer, however it would have been identical to this one.

Comment: i know - moonboots answers are always perfect ;) learned a lot from his answers and his knowledge

Comment: ah ah thanks, if only it was true...  ;)

Answer (score 3):

to build the curve ...

1. add mesh -> circle
2. tab -> edit mode
3. select left half of circle vertices
4. tap x to delete vertices
5. select the 2 left most vertices
6. tag g y to move to the left
7. tab  -> object mode
8. object -> convert to curve

link to video tutorial: https://youtu.be/zROqc01VR90

to move an object along a curve you have to add an object constraint modifier and choose the curve as target.

and here is the link to the tutorial, how you animate an object along a curve: https://youtu.be/ExgB5R5MT0o

Comment: Thanks for your answer! [Gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963/what-is-the-process-for-creating-gifs-for-questions-and-answers) and images may make it much easier to understand...

Comment: i know, that's why i made the video tutorials, which are even better than just pictures... ;)

Comment: Debatable re video tutorials.  IMO there is a slight logic error here. As shown in curve answer extrude the two pole verts of the semicircle, otherwise they will not be quite horizontal.  (and isn't x axis left / right for default circle?)

Comment: yeah....I love confusing people with axis...;) This is the advantage of videos -> you see what the person is doing and if you have luck, with voice explanation. And with many luck, the video was not edited and some important parts deleted ;)